# Limit of a real valued function of two variables.

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac {x²y}{x⁴+y²} = $?
If we take $y = mx^2$,
it comes out to be $\frac {m^2}{1+m^2}$ which depends on $m$, so limit doesn't exist.

How to prove the non existence of limit by using polar form
What I tried –

$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{ r³\cos²(t)\sin(t)}{r³\cos²(t) + r\sin(t)}$

I don't know how to proceed.

I know that limit exists if the result I get is independent of $t$.

Answer (score 2):

Polar form? Don't go polar in terms of $x$ and $y$; substitute $u=x^2$ first. Then it's $\lim_{(u,y)\to (0,0),u\ge 0} \frac{uy}{u^2+y^2}$. Convert that to polar coordinates (the $u\ge 0$ restriction becomes an angle restriction $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le \theta\le \frac{\pi}{2}$) and work from there.

After all, the point of polar coordinates in this sort of question is to make the denominator nice.

Comment: I did as you explained, and I got sin(t)cos(t), which depends on t. But, without converting x^2 to u, why do i get 0 in polar form? Limit should be same.

Comment: The limit along any straight-line path in x and y is zero. Converting to polar right away and looking at constant angles looks only at these straight-line paths - but you already noted that following a parabolic path gets you something else. It's just not enough on its own.